# How to measure the pixel width of the string drawed over Drawing.Bitmap in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, drawing, image-manipulation

I am generating a `.png` image that contains a text dynamically written.

I need to create the bitmap with the minimum width for file size reasons.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Graphics.MeasureString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) to compute the width.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [TextRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer(v=VS.90).aspx) for slightly more accuracy. See this article for differences between this and `Graphics.MeasureString` :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc751527.aspx

Comment: It doesn't return exactly the same results as Graphics.MeasureString, so If the OP wants to know the size of the string actually drawn by the Graphics, Graphics.MeasureString is a better choice